# How can you draw a smooth line or 95% pointwise interval in R?

Tags: r

I have the following image:
[image: Plot]

And I would like to smooth the red and blue line. But I have no idea how to do it. The red and blue lines respectively represent upper & lower 95% intervals of the black dots. 
 (Notice that I didnt use any regression formula to obtain the 95% intervals)
I read about the loess function but when i tried to use it. I get back the same plot. 
So is there any particular built in R function that will allow me to smooth these 2 lines.

Alternatively, is there a way to obtain a **"95% point wise intervals"** for this problem ?

The code is given below:

```
residual.plot <- function(a,b)
{
    log.y1 <- log(a) - b * log(energy)
    fitted.y <- exp(log.y1)
    diff <- count - fitted.y
    #normal approximation
    low.interval <- c()
    high.interval <- c()
    for(i in 1:350)
    {
        low <- diff[i] - sqrt(  exp(log(a) - b * log(energy[i])) )*qnorm(0.975)
        high <- diff[i] + sqrt(  exp(log(a) - b * log(energy[i]))  )*qnorm(0.975)
        low.interval <- append(low.interval, low)
        high.interval <- append(high.interval, high)
    }
    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
    plot(energy, diff, ylim = c(-10,10), type = "p", pch = 7)
    lines(energy, low.interval, type = "p", col = "red", pch = 1)
    lines(energy, high.interval, type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 1)


}
```

Comment: Could you provide your `a` and `b` variables as well? (`dput(a)` and `dput(b)` would be good)

Comment: And where has `count` mysteriously come from? And `energy`? Anyway, if you want smooth 95% intervals you have to compute them from your model. What is your model? Is there a model? I can't actually see one...

Comment: Sorry. count & energy are variables from the dataset , which is defined outside the function.

Comment: a , b are values (can be any numbers)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, never ever dare posting code like that again. You commit two mortal sins :

- you grow objects in an iterative loop (tons of problems there)
- you don't use the fact that R works vectorized.

This said, the easiest way of doing this is by using `lowess`, provided there's no NA values in your data. Your function should be then something like this :

```
residual.plot <- function(a,b,count,energy)
{
    log.y1 <- log(a) - b * log(energy)
    fitted.y <- exp(log.y1)
    diff <- count - fitted.y

    #normal approximation
        low <- diff - sqrt(  exp(log(a) - b * log(energy)) )*qnorm(0.975)
        high <- diff + sqrt(  exp(log(a) - b * log(energy))  )*qnorm(0.975)

    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
    plot(energy, diff, ylim = c(-10,10), type = "p", pch = 7)
    lines(lowess(energy, low), type = "p", col = "red", pch = 1)
    lines(lowess(energy, high), type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 1)


}
```

PS: To make a function useful, you shouldn't count on variables from outside the function like for example `count` and `energy`. Add them as an argument to the function, so you can use the function later on when using a different dataset.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `lines(lowess(energy,low), ...)`

Comment: +1!  I wish I could +2! No so much for the `lowess` bit -which is useful and answers the direct question- but for the few hints about writing _R-ic_ code.  So many newcomers to R fail to get the `vectorized` nature of much of the language. The hint about using `function parameters` is a generic programming best practice, but beware that in R parameters are passed mostly "by-value".   A good read for newbies and even for more seasoned R practitioners is the `R Inferno` (http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @Chinegro The short answer is that many functions and operators in R work on complete vectors, so you don't have to write out loops for that. I strongly advise you to go through the online manuals you can find (plenty of resources) or, if you want, Andrie and I wrote an [introduction book on R](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1119962846/) as well. We keep a strong focus on vectorization through the whole book.